# How can I add zooming to the d3 collapsible tree example?

Tags: javascript, tree, d3.js, zooming

I am trying to add a zooming feature to the d3 collapsible tree [example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html), but can't get it to work. I know there's been a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405638/d3-js-zooming-and-panning-a-collapsible-tree-diagram) and even though it seems rather thorough my changes don't work. The only thing I get is a white page. Probably has to do with the fact that I'm rather new with javascript/d3. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
    pointer-events: all;
}

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

tree {
pointer-events: all;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}



</style>
<body>
<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 1500 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {
  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

    d3.select("svg")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
          .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
          .on("zoom", zoom));


}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);


function zoom() {
    var scale = d3.event.scale,
        translation = d3.event.translate,
        tbound = -h * scale,
        bbound = h * scale,
        lbound = (-w + m[1]) * scale,
        rbound = (w - m[3]) * scale;
    // limit translation to thresholds
    translation = [
        Math.max(Math.min(translation[0], rbound), lbound),
        Math.max(Math.min(translation[1], bbound), tbound)
    ];
    d3.select(".drawarea")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + ")" +
              " scale(" + scale + ")");
}




}

</script>
```

Why does the zoom implementation not work?

Comment: It seems that nothing has the class `drawarea`, which you are selecting in the `zoom` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I played with your code a bit and found several potential issues:

Depending on where/how you are running this, loading the flare.json file could cause a CORS error (eg. if you try to link to the one on bostock's github). You can embed the json object directly in a 'flare' variable and then just move the code you have in the d3.json() method to the bottom of the script and assign the root variable to flare.

```
var flare =  ...paste contents of flare.json here... ;
```

Your javascript methods are defined in an order where you reference methods before they are defined (you should move the zoom and click methods before the update method):

```
collapse(d){...}
zoom(){...}
click(){...}
update(){...}
```

Your zoom method references 'h', 'w', and 'm', which aren't defined anywhere. I assume they are supposed to be width, height, and margin:

```
var zoom = function() {
    var scale = d3.event.scale,
        translation = d3.event.translate,
        tbound = -height * scale,
        bbound = height * scale,
        lbound = (-width + margin.right) * scale,
        rbound = (width - margin.left) * scale;
```

Finally, to fix the zoom thing, you should fix the zoom method like so:

```
var zoom = function() {
    var scale = d3.event.scale,
        translation = d3.event.translate,
        tbound = -height * scale,
        bbound = height * scale,
        lbound = (-width + margin.right) * scale,
        rbound = (width - margin.left) * scale;
    // limit translation to thresholds
    translation = [
        Math.max(Math.min(translation[0], rbound), lbound),
        Math.max(Math.min(translation[1], bbound), tbound)
    ];
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```

Note that I replaced the "select(".drawArea")" with "svg." because you want to transform the top g element (which is what is in the "svg" variable).

Just FYI - I couldn't really get this working in plnkr or jsFiddle because there are weird d3 errors due to the way variables/function scope are handled in plnkr and jsFiddle (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331451/svg-error-permission-denied-to-access-property-somefunction)). That may be an issue someone else can work out. But here's the code in it's entirety (minus the embedded flare.json variable). I ran this code in my own Tomcat container and can double click on the tree and it zooms in. You may want to play around with zooming and panning so that the tree doesn't draw outside of the boundaries of the visibile window (right now if you double click it will zoom, but recenter, so the left side of the tree is off the side of the browser window).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {  pointer-events: all;  }
.node { cursor: pointer;  }
.node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
tree {  pointer-events: all;  }
.node text {  font: 12px sans-serif;  }
.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 1500 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

var collapse = function(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

var zoom = function() {
    var scale = d3.event.scale,
        translation = d3.event.translate,
        tbound = -height * scale,
        bbound = height * scale,
        lbound = (-width + margin.right) * scale,
        rbound = (width - margin.left) * scale;
    // limit translation to thresholds
    translation = [
        Math.max(Math.min(translation[0], rbound), lbound),
        Math.max(Math.min(translation[1], bbound), tbound)
    ];
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + ")" + " scale(" + scale + ")");
}

// Toggle children on click.
var click = function(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
};

var update = function(source) {
    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
        .on("click", click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

    nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
         });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
         })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });

    d3.select("svg")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
        .on("zoom", zoom));
};

d3.json("flare.json", function(json){
    root = json;
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
    root.children.forEach(collapse);
    update(root);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Zoom in&out with drag properties are very easy to appy with collapsible tree. Mainly we must add new version of d3 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/d3.v3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
Are available in [http://d3js.org/][1]


 var vis = d3.select("#box").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("class","svg_container")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .style("overflow", "scroll")
        .style("background-color","#EEEEEE")
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("class","drawarea")
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

    d3.select("svg")   //applying zoom in&out for svg
            .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
                  .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
                  .on("zoom", zoom));

    function zoom() {  //zoom in&out function 
        var scale = d3.event.scale,
            translation = d3.event.translate,
            tbound = -h * scale,
            bbound = h * scale,
            lbound = (-w + m[1]) * scale,
            rbound = (w - m[3]) * scale;
        // limit translation to thresholds
        translation = [
            Math.max(Math.min(translation[0], rbound), lbound),
            Math.max(Math.min(translation[1], bbound), tbound)
        ];
        d3.select(".drawarea")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + ")" +
                  " scale(" + scale + ")");
    }
```